# htaccess photos from main domain to other domains

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have photos on domainA.co.uk which i will be also need to be used on domainB.co.uk and domainC.com, however I only want to store the photos once but reference them on the other domains **BUT appear relative to each domain**.

Is there a way of using htaccess on domainB and domainC to mask the photo url as if they are located on each.

Tried using the below but it redirected to the photo on domainA:

```
RewriteRule ^photos/([0-9]{1,15})-([A-Za-z-0-9_]{1,100}).(jpg|png)$ http://files.domainA.co.uk/location-photos/$2_$1.$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You cant use mod_rewrite for this you will have to look into mod_proxy witch can do what you require you can use it like this: ProxyPass /photos http://files.domainA.co.uk/location-photos/

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen: how should i be applying ProxyPass the my code? where should i be applying this? and how do i ensure that if any other domains try using the proxy that i can block or redirect them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without use of `proxy`.

You will need to enable mod_proxy in your Apache config for that on `domainB` and on `domainC`. Once mod_proxy is enabled, enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^photos/([0-9]{1,15})-([A-Za-z-0-9_]{1,100}).(jpg|png)$ http://files.domainA.co.uk/location-photos/$2_$1.$3 [NC,L,P]
```

**UPDATE:** As per comments, try this rule to restrict this rule for certain domains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hh\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^photos/destinations/(.+?\.(?:jpg|png))$ http://cdn.ac.co.uk/photos/location/$1 [NC,L,P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chi\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^media/photos/(.+?\.(?:jpg|png))$ http://cdn.ac.co.uk/photos/location/$1 [NC,L,P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^media\.cc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^files/assets/photos/(.+?\.(?:jpg|png))$ http://cdn.ac.co.uk/photos/location/$1 [NC,L,P]
```

Comment: Or in the vhost conf obviously

Comment: @anubhava, thanks for your answer, mod_proxy and mod_rewrite are both enabled on my server. How do i restrict it so that only the domains i set link to this proxy as i gather its could be a security whole which  could be exploited?

Comment: So you want to allow mod_proxy for certain domains only? Or want some other restriction?

Comment: For example chi.co.uk / cc.com / hh.co.uk and some others will all have different content, however they all need to reference some files on a sub-domain cdn.ac.co.uk

Instead of the files for each domain having a file urls of http://cdn.ac.co.uk/photos/location/photoA.jpg, each of the above domains need to reference this file but when linking to the file the url should appear individual to that domain... i.e.

http://www.chi.co.uk/media/photos/photoA.jpg
http://media.cc.com/files/assets/photos/photoA.jpg
http://www.hh.co.uk/photos/destinations/photoA.jpg

Comment: ... and i also want to be able to restrict access so that only domains/sub-domains which i set are to be allowed access to any files. And any other domains to be blocked or redirected to a url or image

Comment: @DavidG: Ok I am on mobile. I will update my answer as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: @anubhava: sorry one final question... ive seen some mentions of ProxyPass, should i be applying ProxyPass and if so how would i add this to my code?

Comment: I don't think you will need ProxyPass if you use code as suggested.